# How to get cameras local x-axis pointing up?

Tags: camera, constraints, tracking, path

I have my Camera moving along a Path, and following an object with a damped track constraint, but i does some weird movement, like rotating on its own. In order to fix it I would like to make the local x-Axis of the camera always facing upwards. How can I do this? Is there a Constraint for that?

(I have deleted all rotation frames, but it still is messy, I also have tried to lock the axis, on the n-panel but since this is global it won't work..)

Answer (score 6):

You probably want to use the "Track To" constraint. Then you can configure which axis should point to the object, and which axis should point upward. For a camera this would be typically -Z for the "To" axis, and Y for the "Up" axis:

[image: Track To example]

Comment: thanks, but that wasn't what i was looking for.

Comment: Well, maybe you can explain what is the difference between this and what you are actually looking for?